# What is this notation with an un-sandwiched comma in the subscript?

Tags: notation, differentiation

I have a scalar deflection potential (in the study of weak lensing) and in the book (Schneider, Kochanek and Wambsganss's *Gravitational Lensing: Strong, Weak and Micro*) I have the following passage:

> If a source is much smaller than the angular scale on which the lens properties change, the lens mapping can be linearised locally. The distortion of images is then described by
>
> $$
> \vec{A}(\vec{\theta})
>  =\frac{\partial\vec{\beta}}{\partial\vec{\theta}}
>  =\Big(\delta_{ij}-\frac{\partial^2\psi(\vec{\theta})}{\partial\theta_i\theta_j}\Big)
>  =\begin{pmatrix}
>   1-\kappa-\gamma_1 &\gamma_2\\
>   \gamma & -\kappa+\gamma_1\end{pmatrix}$$
>
> where we have introduced the components of the shear $\gamma=\gamma_1+i\gamma_2=|\gamma|e^{2i\phi}$, $$\gamma_1=\frac{1}{2}(\psi_{,11}-\psi_{,22}),$$ $$\gamma_2=\psi_{,12}.$$

So there it is in context. Could someone please explan the notation used in the scalar potentials on the last 2 lines?

Comment: It's a derivative with respect to the coordinates indicated after the comma.

Comment: Matrices using `\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}`.

Comment: Those are the $\partial^2\psi(\theta)/\partial\theta_i\partial\theta_j$.

Answer (score 0):

It means a partial derivative, the same as it usually does. In this case, $\psi$ is as scalar field, so it has no indices of its own, so there is nothing to "sandwich" (your word) the comma against on the left side of the subscript.